# How to draw over a UIImageView?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have a `UIView` with a `UIImageView` added as a subview. I want to be able to draw OVER the `UIImageView`, but the drawing goes behind it. I’ve tried drawing the `UIImage` explicitly though I’m not too familiar with drawing the image of `UIImage` onto the `UIView`. I’ve read that drawing my image in `drawInRect` results in low performance and lagginess and that was what I saw.

Here’s a function that in which I’ve tried drawing my uiimage to the view. Nothing happens.

```
func setBitmapImage() {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
    bitmapImage?.draw(in: bounds) // bounds of the view I’m drawing on
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
}
```

Any suggestions? Huge thanks!

[image]

Comment: a simple Hacky way is to put a transparent view on top of your image view
that may cover super view as well and draw everything on that transparent view

Comment: I've tried that, but when I add the image view it seems to go on top of that transparent view. Unfortunately the drawing goes behind it.

Comment: The way I did it was trying to do fauxView.addSubview(imageView). Faux view would be the layer behind the transparent view. It would still go on top of the transparent view.

Comment: when you add image view bring your transparent view to front using code like this `[self.view bringSubviewToFront:transparentView];`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this to switch the order of your `UIView's subviews`

```
[self.view exchangeSubviewAtIndex:[self.view.subViews indexOfObject:yourImageView] withSubviewAtIndex:
[self.view.subViews indexOfObject:theViewOnWhichYouAreDrawing]];
```